# Attribute error: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, attributes, pygame

I have an attribute error which is stopping me from continuing, is anyone able to debug it. I have tried moving things around in the ball class but nothing has worked. I am stuck.

```
        import random
        import pygame

        class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self, x, y):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
                self.image.fill((160, 70, 0))
                self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)
                self.x = self.rect.x
                self.y = self.rect.y
                self.speed_x = 0
                self.speed_y = 0
                self.radiusx = 0
                self.radiusy = 100
                self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
                # Pass the midbottom position as an argument to `get_rect`.
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midbottom=(x, y))
                # Set the x and y attributes afterwards.
                # Alternatively.
                #self.rect.midbottom = x, y

            def update(self, screen_rect):  # Pass a rect with the size of the screen.
                self.x += self.speed_x
                self.y += self.speed_y
                self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
                if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
                    # Clamp the rect if it's outside of the screen.
                    self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
                    self.x, self.y = self.rect.topleft

            def render(self, screen):
                screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

The error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maxi/Desktop/Pygame_Resources/codingandcaring github/Stack Overflow Help.py", line 233, in 
    main()
  File "/Users/maxi/Desktop/Pygame_Resources/codingandcaring github/Stack Overflow Help.py", line 101, in main
    basketball = Ball(start_x, start_y)
  File "/Users/maxi/Desktop/Pygame_Resources/codingandcaring github/Stack Overflow Help.py", line 9, in **init**
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)
AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'x'

```
        class Goal(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self, x, y):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                # self.image = pygame.image.load('goal.png').convert_alpha()
                # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (220, 220))
                self.image = pygame.Surface((220, 220)).convert_alpha()
                self.image.fill((60, 80, 110))
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 220, 220)

            def render(self, screen):
                screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


        class Ring(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self, x, y):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                # self.image = pygame.image.load('ring.png').convert_alpha()
                # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (400, 400))
                self.image = pygame.Surface((400, 400)).convert_alpha()
                self.image.fill((60, 180, 110))
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
                self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 400, 400)
                self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

            def render(self, screen):
                screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


        class Baddie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self, x, y, z):
                # self.image = pygame.image.load().convert_alpha()
                # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (220, 220))
                self.image = pygame.Surface((90, 90)).convert_alpha()
                self.image.fill((250, 50, 0))
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.x = x
                self.y = y

            def render(self, screen):
                screen.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

        def pause():
            while True:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            return

        def main():
            width = 1200
            height = 722

            pygame.init()
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
            screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Add a clock to limit the frame rate.
            pygame.display.set_caption('Basketball Shootout')
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
            start_x, start_y = screen_rect.midbottom
            basketball = Ball(start_x, start_y)
            snd_file = 'Game.ogg'
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load(snd_file)
            mixer.music.play()


            badtimer = 100
            badtimer1 = 0
            badguys = [[640, 100]]

            # court = pygame.image.load('halfcourt.jpg')
            # court = pygame.transform.scale(court, (1200, 722))
            court = pygame.Surface((1200, 722))
            court.fill((30, 30, 30))
            basketball = Ball(50, 50)
            goal = Goal(487, 0)
            ring = Ring(400, 400)
            # The player is not needed since the `basketball` is already
            # the playable ball instance.
            # player = Ball  # Just remove this line.

            # badguyimg1 = pygame.image.load("wpierdol.png")
            # badguyimg1 = pygame.transform.scale(badguyimg1, (100, 100))
            # badguyimg2 = pygame.image.load("bad_guy2.gif")
            # badguyimg2 = pygame.transform.scale(badguyimg2, (100, 100))
            # badguyimg3 = pygame.image.load("bad_guy3.gif")
            # badguyimg3 = pygame.transform.scale(badguyimg3, (100, 100))
            badguyimg1 = pygame.Surface((90, 90))
            badguyimg1.fill((60, 50, 210))
            badguyimg2 = pygame.Surface((90, 90))
            badguyimg2.fill((250, 50, 210))
            badguyimg3 = pygame.Surface((90, 90))
            badguyimg3.fill((250, 50, 130))
            badlist = [badguyimg1, badguyimg2, badguyimg3]

            score = 0  # The score variable was missing.

            stop_game = False

            while not stop_game:
                # Event handling.
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        stop_game = True
                    # Either set the speed here or increment the `basketball.y`
                    # in the while loop with `pygame.key.get_pressed`.
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                            basketball.speed_y = -5
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                            basketball.speed_y = 5
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                            basketball.speed_x = -5
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            basketball.speed_x = 5
                    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                        # Stop the ball.
                        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                            basketball.speed_y = 0
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                            basketball.speed_y = 0
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and basketball.speed_x < 0:
                            basketball.speed_x = 0
                        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and basketball.speed_x > 0:
                            basketball.speed_x = 0

                # Don't call get_pressed in the event loop (for every event).
                # pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                # if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                #     basketball.y -= 5
                # elif pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                #     basketball.y += 5
                # if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:  # if not elif, to separate vertical and horizontal movement.
                #     basketball.x -= 5
                # elif pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                #     basketball.x += 5

                # Updating.
                basketball.update(screen_rect)
                badtimer -= 1

                point = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(basketball, ring)  # Use basketball not player.
                if point:
                    # The score will be incremented continually.
                    score = score + 1
                    pygame.font.init() # you have to call this at the start, 
                    # if you want to use this module.
                    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
                    textsurface = myfont.render('%d' %(score), False, (0, 0, 0))
                    screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))

                # Update the bad guys.
                if badtimer == 0:
                    badguys.append([1040, random.randint(50,430)])
                    badtimer = 100-(badtimer1*2)
                if badtimer1 >= 35:
                    badtimer1 = 35
                else:
                    badtimer1 += 5

                # You can `enumerate` the badguys list to get the index
                # and the item at the same time.
                for index, badguy in enumerate(badguys[:]):
                    if badguy[0] < -64:
                        # Don't modify a list while you're iterating over it.
                        # Iterate over a slice copy: badguys[:]
                        badguys.pop(index)
                    badguy[0] -= 7

                # Drawing.
                screen.blit(court, (0,0))

                text = font.render(
                    'Dodge the other team to get to the goal!',
                    True, (0, 0, 0))
                screen.blit(text, (430, 630))
                goal.render(screen)
                # You forgot to render the ring.
                ring.render(screen)

                for badguy in badguys:
                    screen.blit(badguyimg1, badguy)  # The `dest`ination arg was missing.

                basketball.render(screen)

                pygame.display.update()
                clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.

            pygame.quit()

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
```

There may be more errors within the code, I am unsure as I tried to work past the attribute error and add other things in. Please test with all the code.

Comment: You should add the full traceback and indent the code properly

Comment: You have to define the `self.x` and `self.y` attributes before you use them to create the rect.

Answer (score 2):

In your `__init__()` method for `Ball` (line #9), you reference `self.x` (and `self.y`), but you haven't set those variables.

Comment: When I moved the line 'self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100) ' it said :

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/maxi/Desktop/Pygame_Resources/codingandcaring github/Stack Overflow Help.py", line 233, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/maxi/Desktop/Pygame_Resources/codingandcaring github/Stack Overflow Help.py", line 101, in main
    basketball = Ball(start_x, start_y)
  File "/Users/maxi/Desktop/Pygame_Resources/codingandcaring github/Stack Overflow Help.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.x = self.rect.x
AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'rect'

Comment: @MaxCOSSETTO, I think you are missing the point. You cannot reference objects before they have been defined. Perhaps you should be doing something with the `x, y` that are arguments to your `Ball.__init__()` method as mentioned by @skrx?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable or an attribute before you've defined it. Either pass `x` and `y` to `pygame.Rect` instead of `self.x`, `self.y`,

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100, 100)).convert_alpha()
        self.image.fill((160, 70, 0))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)
        self.x = self.rect.x
        self.y = self.rect.y
```

or assign `x` and `y` to `self.x`, `self.y` first and create the rect afterwards:

```
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)
```

Comment: the same thing happened for another sprite, I tried using the same method here but the method does not seem to work. 'self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)'

Comment: Make sure that the variables or attributes are defined before you use them. I'd have to see your code in order to tell you what exactly is wrong.

Comment: class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(badguy_file).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (100, 100))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)
        self.x = self.rect.x
        self.y = self.rect.y
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(1,0)

Comment: There are no `x, y` variables in the `__init__` method, but you're trying to pass them here `pygame.Rect(x, y, 100, 100)`. Where should these variables come from? You need to define them or pass them to the `__init__` method, e.g. `def __init__(self, x, y):` and then create the `Mob` in this way `mob = Mob(200, 300)`. I recommend reading a tutorial like [Program Arcade Games](http://programarcadegames.com/) to learn the basics.

Comment: BTW, it's better to ask new questions instead of posting your code in the comments. But always try to solve the problem on your own first, describe what you've tried and add an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you post a question on SO.